# Using multiple AND conditions in one IFS fromula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I’m trying to make sheets calculate my delivery times based on which locations the items are shipped between.

Tried combining the Ifs and `AND` formulas, but I keep getting errors.

(Let’s say the delivery time between London and Barcelona is 5 days.
Delivery time between Stockholm and Madrid is 6 days.
A3=today’s date)

My formula looks like this right now:

```
=Ifs(And(A1=London,A2=Barcelona), A3+5, AND(A1=Stockholm,A2=Madrid), A3+6
```

And so on. I have at least 11 different delivery times depending on destinations. How can I make this formula run?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few problems,

firstly are you passing two conditions ? Must A1 be London and A2 be Barcelona for the formula to equate to true?

secondly, you need to wrap any strings in " " so Google sheets knows it's a string and not an integer.

This worked for me :

```
=Ifs(And(A2="London",A3="Barcelona"), A4+1)
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cwQv28S9T99JQsJbDX0JtQnoEYeAUivo6pyaHpGsgkw/edit?usp=sharing

updated formula to have 7 possibilities, basically you put your bracket in the incorrect place, read the docs next time, I know formulas can be scary at first but they follow a set logic =)

```
  =Ifs(And(A2="London",A3="Barcelona"), A4+1,
AND(A2="Stockholm", A3="Madrid"),A4+4, 
AND(A2="Germany", A3="Birmingham"),A4+15,
AND(A2="India", A3="China"),A4+5,
AND(A2="Glasgow", A3="Taiwan"),A4+75,
AND(A2="Munich", A3="Portugal"),A4+25,
AND(A2="North Korea", A3="South Korea"),A4+4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have more flexibility — and a much shorter formula — if you set up a separate sheet where you kept your destinations and hours, then had the first sheet reference that in a VLOOKUP, like this:[image: Two-Sheet Approach]

`=A3 + VLOOKUP("*"&A1&"*"&A2&"*", 'Trip Times'!A:B, 2, FALSE)`